# Separating a number within a column in awk or grep

Tags: awk, grep, split

I am writing a script that will process files that are similar in all columns but the first one ,$1. What I want to redirect to another file is dependent on the value of the third column and that I know how to discriminate for, but I want to redirect the "id"-number in the first column, not the whole first column:

Different input file formats:

```
1452123_s_at        0.45609 1.55e-04    7.85    -2.89   2.657
145243_s_at         0.35709 1.46e-04    7.7     -2.9    2.713

Xl.15267.1.A1_at    0.45609 1.79e-04    7.66    -2.9    2.21
Xl.14257.1.A1_at    0.76509 1.67e-04    7.85    -2.87   2.23

160919_r_at         0.45609 1.83e-04    -7.63   -2.9    -2.888
145916_r_at         0.41869 3.82e-04    -7.56   -2.8    -2.798

162334_r_at         0.51869 2.49e-04    -7.24   -2.93   -2.095
15356_r_at          0.68229 1.79e-04    -7.45   -2.88   -2.5

160365_at           0.68223 3.82e-04    -6.72   -2.98   -1.795
16345_at            0.45623 2.94e-04    -5.99   -2.45   -1.568

26768               0.51869 1.83e-04    7.66    -2.9     2.21
30075               0.67749 1.46e-04    7.45    -2.89    2.34
```

Desired output:

```
1452123     1.55e-04    
145243      1.46e-04    
15267       1.79e-04    
14257       1.67e-04    
160919      1.83e-04    
145916      3.82e-04    
162334      2.49e-04    
15356       1.79e-04    
160365      3.82e-04    
16345       2.94e-04    
26768       1.83e-04    
30075       1.46e-04
```

This number can be pretty much anything between 1-10 000 000 and the structure of the whole first column can vary a bit more than this example but it will always have this number somewhere within it. Is there any way of writing something universal enough to recognize and print this number only? By using split or if somehow maybe?

It doesn't matter which program that is used, awk, grep or sed, I'm just looking for the most efficient way of doing it. 
I'm also pretty new to the command line, so please explain plainly and the different commands!
Thanks

Comment: Can there be other symbols besides . and _ that will separate the id from the rest of the first column?

Comment: In `Xl.15267.1.A1_at` how can a script tell that `15267` is the desired number instead of `1`? Because it's the first number in the line? Because it's the biggest? Because it has multiple digits? Something else?

Comment: I don't think there should be other separators than . and _ but I can't be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the patterns belong to a finite set. So the patterns can be listed. To simplify the process I created a [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) version:

```
awk '
NF && ( match($1,/^([0-9]+)((_[rs])?_at)?$/,a) ||
match($1,/^Xl\.([0-9]+)\.1\.A1_at$/,a) ) {
    printf("%-12s%-s\n", substr($1, a[1,"start"], a[1,"length"]), $3)
}
' inputfile
```

The first `match` checks for four patterns: `<NUM>_s_at`, `<NUM>_r_at`, `<NUM>_at`, `<NUM>`. The last `Xl.<NUM>.1.A1_at`. Then cuts off the matched number and formats the output.

Output:

```
1452123     1.55e-04
145243      1.46e-04
15267       1.79e-04
14257       1.67e-04
160919      1.83e-04
145916      3.82e-04
162334      2.49e-04
15356       1.79e-04
160365      3.82e-04
16345       2.94e-04
26768       1.83e-04
30075       1.46e-04
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `gsub()` to remove not numeric values and then print:

```
awk 'NF{gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$1); print $1, $3}' file
```

It returns:

```
1452123 1.55e-04
145243 1.46e-04
1526711 1.79e-04
1425711 1.67e-04
160919 1.83e-04
145916 3.82e-04
162334 2.49e-04
15356 1.79e-04
160365 3.82e-04
16345 2.94e-04
26768 1.83e-04
30075 1.46e-04
```

#### Explanation

- `NF` perform the following command in `{}` just if `NF` is true, that is, if the line is not empty.
- `gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",$1)` for the 1st field, remove all characters not in the range `0-9`. That is, remove all non-numerical values.
- `print $1, $3` print the 1st and 3rd fields.

Comment: rows 2 and 3 don't match.

Comment: well they contain an extra 1 coming from the trailing `1` on `Xl.15267.1.A1_at`

Comment: @fedorqui I understand why they are there.  But they don't match the OP's requirements.

Comment: @fedorqui: Maybe the first 2+ digit number could solve the issue. Sg. like `match($1,/([0-9]{2,})/)`, then `substr($1,RSTART, RLENGTH)` gives the proper number. For [tag:gawk] --re-interval could be needed...

Comment: @TrueY thank you very much for the trick. I am not familiar with `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`, so I will try to get familiar with it during the day :)

Comment: @Degustaf yes, let's see what the OP comments below his question, as he was requested to clarify.

Comment: honestly, I'm very new to this, so I will have to try it and read more to see if it works, but thanks!

Comment: alright, yeah sorry, will do! I think the last one is what I'm looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will split over the non-digit chars, and pick up the largest number left. Below is my implementation, and thanks @fedorqui for his NF trick

```
NF{n=split($1,a,/[^0-9]+/); v=a[1]; for(i=2; i<=n; i++) { if (v<a[i]) v=a[i]; } print v, $3}
```

Answer (score 0):

WIth GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk 'NF{ print gensub(/([^._]*[._])?([[:digit:]]+).*/,"\\2","",$1), $3 }' file
1452123 1.55e-04
145243 1.46e-04
15267 1.79e-04
14257 1.67e-04
160919 1.83e-04
145916 3.82e-04
162334 2.49e-04
15356 1.79e-04
160365 3.82e-04
16345 2.94e-04
26768 1.83e-04
30075 1.46e-04
```